# Update only an object from another object and keep the rest of parameters the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a structure like the following:

```
{
    firstname: '',
    company: {id: '', name: ''},
    nextAction: { by: '',
                  type: {id: '', name: ''}
                }
}
```

And the following functions to update the parameters ':

```
const handleInputValue = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
const { name, value } = e.target;

if (name === 'firstName') {
  setValues({
    ...values,
    [name]: value,
  });
  validate({ [name]: value });
} else if (name === 'company') {
  setValues({
    ...values,
    [name]: { name: name, id: value },
  });
  validate({ [name]: value });
} else if (name === 'nextAction') {
  setValues({
    ...values,
    nextAction: { ...nextAction, value: { name: name, id: value } },
  });
  validate({ [name]: value });
}
```

It works to update 'firstname' and 'company' and I want to update only the 'type' for the 'nextAction' and keep the initial value for 'by' but I think the syntax is wrong. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`else if (name === 'nextAction') { setValues({ ...values, nextAction: { ...values.nextAction, value: { name: name, id: value } }, }); validate({ [name]: value }); }`

You can spread the values by using `...values.nextAction`